# In C# What is the best way to filter out of this collection?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a list of Room objects, each room object has a Building attribute;

```
 public class Room
{
      public string BuildingName;
      public string Name 
}
```

I now want to filter my collection where i only take 1 room from each building (I don't care which one)

so for example

```
 var room = new Room(){BuildingName ="Building 1", Name = "Room 1"};
 var room2 = new Room(){BuildingName ="Building 1", Name = "Room 2"};
 var room3 = new Room(){BuildingName ="Building 2", Name = "Room 3"};
 var room4 = new Room(){BuildingName ="Building 2", Name = "Room 4"};
 var room5 = new Room(){BuildingName ="Building 2", Name = "Room 5"};

 var ListofRooms = new List<Room> {room, room2, room3, room4, room5};
```

in this case i would want to run this list through a function that would return an array with 2 items (one from each Building)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is pretty convenient for this sort of task:

```
var result = ListofRooms.GroupBy(room => room.BuildingName)
                        .Select(buildingGroup => buildingGroup.First())
                        .ToList();
```

What this does is create a bucket for each building (consisting of the rooms in the building), then select a room from each bucket, before finally materializing the selected rooms into a collection.

Some tangential points:

1. Standard C# naming conventions dictate that local variables should be named in camelCase (`listOfRooms`), not PascalCase(`ListofRooms`).
2. If you like, you can get rid of the parantheses for the parameterless constructor in the object-initializers, like this: `new Room { BuildingName = "Building 1", Name = "Room 1" }`

If you don't want to use LINQ for this, I would do:

```
var seenBuildingNames = new HashSet<string>();
var result = new List<Room>();

foreach(var room in ListofRooms)
{
    if(seenBuildingNames.Add(room.BuildingName))
    {
        // First time we are encountering this building; add room to result.
        result.Add(room);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach:

```
var result = ListofRooms.Distinct(new BuildingEqualityComparer());
```

And the class `BuildingEqualityComparer` is as follows:

```
public class BuildingEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Room>
{
    public bool Equals(Room x, Room y)
    {
        return x.BuildingName.Equals(y.BuildingName);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Room obj)
    {
        return obj.BuildingName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This approach is actually rarelly used because you need to make an implementation of `IEqualityComparer` which is a PITA, but it's just another way of achieving what you need, so if you like it or find it simpler, use it!!!